# How to insert new row in client database using Microsoft Sync Framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

I followed the tutorial "Tutorial: Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Server Compact" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928494.aspx) everything worked fine.

After the last step, when I want to add an new row in the client database (dbf database file) I receive the following error "The number of columns in the query and the table must match. [ Number of columns in query = 3, Number of columns in table = 6]"

I know that the synk framework has inserted Sync columns at the end of the tables I want to edit on the client device, but do I have to manage these columns ? And if yes, what must I exactely fill in these cols ?

Thank you in advance for your answer

J-D Gasser

Comment: Which specific step in the tutorial did it fail and what columns were added by sync fx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this has been answered in your other post in the MSDN forums ([link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a9a67007-b2af-4e44-ab43-6e8c959b10c1/how-to-insert-new-row-in-client-database?forum=syncdevdiscussions)) and the issue has nothing to do with Sync Fx (you will get the same error whether you use Sync fx or not)

as advised, please make sure to specify the columns in your Insert statement (e.g., insert into tablex(col1, col2, col3) values (col1value, col2value, col3value)